# How can I create a powershell script to connect to network shared folders?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, shared-directory

I have the following piece of script:

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your user'
$pwd = Read-Host -Promt 'Input your password'

$Server = '\\10.218.NN.NN\Folder'

echo "net use f: $Server /u:domain\$username $pwd"


net use "f: $Server /u:domain\$username $pwd"
```

I have the echo return the output of my script, as its the following:

`net use f: \\10.218.108.49\Soporte /u:domain\user.name password`

Running it via script shows the following error:

```
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

But running the exact same command with CMD connects the folder properly. How can I be able to map network folders with my script without failing?

Comment: Is this a typo in your question, or in your actual code, `-Promt`? Also you need to remove the doublequotes which are making a single argument to `net use` instead of the four arguments it is supposed to be receiving.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes in the last line of code:

```
net use f: $Server /u:domain\$username $pwd
```